# Is it possible to get HTML Response in a Java Servlet

Tags: html, java-server

Considering that I am running http java servlet, I would like to have my index.html have an alert from my java servlet. Most of the example I found on web are of .jsp but I am using html/html5 implementation. I would like to be able use javascript to call my server and display the server message.

The alert should display the String message "This is the response"

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class JavaHttpServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
        server.createContext("/test", new MyHandler());
        server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
        server.start();
    }

    static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
            String response = "This is the response";
            t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
            OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
            os.write(response.getBytes());
            os.close();
        }
    }

}
```

I have a index.html as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function start() {

        var eventSource = new EventSource("http://localhost:8000/test");

      eventSource.onmessage = function(event) {

    alert(event.data);

        };

    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Two options are embedding the server side error message in the JSP and creating a service which can return an error code.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen what do you mean, does it mean not possible?

Comment: Update your question and clearly elaborate on the alert and when/why it should happen.